# Using predict() in R to predict the y-value for multiple occurrences of the same x-value

Tags: r, prediction, prediction-interval

If I have a linear model and want to use `predict()` to predict the mean and confidence interval of multiple ($m$) new observations of a given x-value ($x_h$), how do I account for the $m$ in the formula for the $s$ of the predicted mean?
$$
{\rm MSE}(\frac 1 m + \frac 1 n + \frac{(x_h - \bar x)^2}{S_{xx}})
$$

Is it the `weight` argument? Or do I have to include the desired $x_h$ $m$ times in the `newdata`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `weights` argument will work -- just set it equal to $m$ in your formula. It will *not* work to put multiple instances of $x_h$ in `newdata` -- you'll just get several copies of the same interval.

Another approach is to use `pred.var = summary(mod)$sigma^2 / m` where `mod` is your model and `m` is your value of $m$. The reason this works is that `pred.var` is used to set the variance of future observations; by default it is assumed to be the same as in the data ($\sigma^2$, estimated by $MSE$). By pretending it is $\sigma^2/m$ (estimated as $MSE/m$), you are using the variance of the average of $m$ predictions and will produce the correct result.

Comment: The documentation states: "This can be a multiple of res.var, the estimated value of σ^2". Does that mean that `res.var` is the same as `summary(mod)$sigma^2`?

Comment: If `weights` will work, do you want to consider changing the top part of your answer for others' future reference?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. `res.var` is a variable internal to `predict.lm` that is equal to that value.

Comment: @KevinM: Took me a while, but I made the change.

Comment: Looks great! I can't upvote on this site yet.